# Passing an array through filter does not narrow element type

Tags: typescript, filter

I have an interface with two optional properties:

```tsx
interface A {
  one?: string;
  two?: string;
}
```

Then I'd like to pass them inside of an array to a component that expects `string[]`

```tsx
export const MyComponent: React.FunctionComponent<A> = ({one, two}) => {
  return <Query props={[one, two].filter(Boolean)} />
}
```

Even though I remove the undefined values with `filter(Boolean)`, ts will still complain with the error:

> Type '(string | undefined)[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.

Is this some kind of design issue and the only way is to do typecasting of

```tsx
  return <Query props={[one, two].filter(Boolean) as string[]} />
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filter` can narrow down the type of an array, but only if you pass it a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) as the function. The Boolean constructor does not have the appropriate types.

For example, in the following code, the return type `val is string` means "this will return a boolean, and if it returns true, assume that `val` is a string":

```
[one, two].filter((val: string | undefined): val is string => Boolean(val));
```

If you're doing this a lot, you may want to make a reusable function:

```
const notUndefined = <T>(val: T | undefined): val is T => Boolean(val);
// used like:
[one, two].filter(notUndefined)
```